# Django Backend loop to a frontend list

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Sorry for the question, but I'm begginer in Django and I don't find any topic like this case.

This is the code:

views.py

```
def select_collections(request):
    listacolecao = Collection.objects.order_by('upload_date')
        
    listasubscription = Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    for obj in listacolecao:
                try:
                    Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user, collection=obj)
                except Subscription.DoesNotExist:
                    print('not exist')
                else:
                    print('Ok')
```

It prints this result in terminal:

```
not exist
not exist
Ok
not exist
Ok
Ok
Ok
Ok
```

I know that isn't a list, but I need to put it result into a template. How can I do that?

Thank

Comment: why you are not trying the same methode in template side? is ther any other purpose

Comment: Because I don't know how can I do that. I tried filter ```Subscription``` with ```Collection``` objects in template side, but I can't.

Comment: Do filtering in the ´view.py´ and pass the result to the template and simple template for loop will do the work

Comment: I need that appear the objects DoesNotExist too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the same you had there but printed in a template you have, (in my humble and beginners opinion) you would need to modify a little bit your view, create a template where you want to display it and modify the url to load the view in that template, something like:

View.py changes:

```
def select_collections(request):
    listacolecao = Collection.objects.order_by('upload_date')
    listasubscription = Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    a_list = [] #You would get something like: ['not exist', 'not exist', 'Ok', 'not exist', 'Ok','Ok','Ok'] which is what it was printed in your code
    for obj in listacolecao:
                try:
                    Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user, collection=obj)
                except Subscription.DoesNotExist:
                    #print('not exist') I would substitute it for .append, to add each value to the list as a new item
                    a_list.append('not exist')
                else:
                    #print('Ok')
                    a_list.append('Ok')
   
    
#Now you pass that variable and sending it to your template, so you can use it there.
    context = {
    'a_list':a_list, 
    }
    
    return render(request, 'your_template_name.html', context)
```

In your urls.py:

```
from .views import select_collections #Importing your recently created view

urlpatterns = [
   path = ('the_url_where_you_want_it', select_collections, name="the_name_you_prefer" ),
]
```

Now in your template per se:

```
#As you have already sent those variables here you can use Django's template tags

{% for each_obj in a_list %}
    <h3> {{each_obj }} </h3> #If you change each_obj for a_list, you would get a QuerySet (fancy word for a list), with all the items in the "a_list" variable.
{% endfor %}
```

That should allow you to see each item of the list individually in your template.

Comment: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'a_list' referenced before assignment

I tried put ```a_list = []``` upon ```for obj in listacolecao:```. The error disappeared, but all the results were: ```[ 'Ok', 'Ok', 'Ok', 'Ok', 'Ok', 'Ok', 'Ok',].

Comment: define `a_list` before appending something in to it

Comment: Sorry, @AdhunThalekkara is right, I was copying and pasting and did not really see it at the time, but if you don't declare your list first, you won't have anything to append to.

Comment: @Victor Pérez Asuaje, I only change in ```Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user, collection=obj)```, ```filter``` to ```get```. It's work perfect. More one life saved. Thanks!

Comment: @Felipe I'm glad to know that! ;)